# Non-Free Finitely Generated Injective Modules over a Local Ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I was wondering if someone could be so kind as to provide an example of a local ring $ (R,\frak{m}) $ and a non-free finitely generated injective module over $ R $. Thank you very much! I tried searching everywhere online, but my attempts have been a total failure so far.

Comment: Let $k$ be a field. Then $(k, (0))$ is a local ring, and $k$ is a finitely-generated injective (and projective and free!) $k$-module.

Comment: Did you try Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module Several examples there.

Comment: Oops! I forgot to mention that the module has to be non-free.

Comment: The simplest non-self-injective local algebra I can think of is $R = k[x,y]/(xy,x^2,y^2), \mathfrak{m}=(x,y)$. There will be a unique indecomposable injective.  Have you tried it?

Comment: @mt_: Thanks! Actually, you could make that an official answer. By the way, does this example appear in Lam's book *Lectures on Modules and Rings*?

Comment: @HaskellCurry you're welcome.  I don't know if it's in Lam's book I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example would be $R = k[x,y]/(xy,x^2,y^2), \mathfrak{m}=(x,y)$, with $I$ the unique indecomposable injective.